# This opens to the correct prompt, but when I hit enter nothing happens

Tags: javascript

I copied a multi-search script from a website, I changed only what it told me to. Then I saved as an HTML file and ran in Chrome. But when I enter a word and hit enter, nothing happens. I know nothing about computers, so I don't know where to begin

Doesn't run on Explorer or Firefox either

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style=”background-color:grey”>

<p>What German word would you like to multisearch? Type below, then press enter please.</p>
<input type=”text” id=”boxu” autofocus>

<script>
document.getElementById(“boxu”).onkeydown = function(e) {searchy(e)};
function searchy(e)
{
if (e.which == 13)
{
var q = document.getElementById(“boxu”).value;
window.open(“http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D” + q + “%26num%3D10%26hl%3Dde%26tbo%3Dd%26site%3Dimghp%26tbm%3Disch%26sout%3D1%26biw%3D1075%26bih%3D696”);
window.open(“http://www.forvo.com/word/” + q + “/#de”);
window.open(“https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/” + q);
document.getElementById(“boxu”).value = “”;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your use of `“` is wrong. You are using a certain type of quote typically provided by rich text editors that cannot be used in JavaScript or HTML. Use `"` not `“`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below-
Include the `onkeydown` function inside the `textbox` input. When inside the script the function isn't getting called.And as a comment suggests you are using the wrong "". Fixed that too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:grey">

<p>What German word would you like to multisearch? Type below, then press enter please.</p>
<input type="text" id="boxu" autofocus onkeydown="searchy(event)">

<script>

function searchy(e)
{
   console.log(e)
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
   console.log("a");
var q = document.getElementById("boxu").value;
window.open("http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D" + q + "%26num%3D10%26hl%3Dde%26tbo%3Dd%26site%3Dimghp%26tbm%3Disch%26sout%3D1%26biw%3D1075%26bih%3D696");
window.open("http://www.forvo.com/word/" + q + "/#de");
window.open("https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/" + q);
document.getElementById("boxu").value = "";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it helped you please vote and mark the answer as correct so it can help others too

Comment: Did it. Thank you